# CPU-Instructions vs. Duration

Tags: c++, duration, instructions

I have two different programs for solving a mathematic problem written in C++(program `A` and `B`).
`A` performs round about 10 times better (in terms of duration) than `B`. Now I counted the executed CPU instructions via the valgrind tool callgrind and realized that program `A` needs just 1/3 of the instructions executed by program `B`. I would have expected the factor being around 1/10.
I know there are CPU instructions that take more CPU cycles (like memory access), but by design `A` should include a bunch more of this expensive instructions than `B`.
Also I don't know how callgrind counts such instructions (couldn't find anything about this in documentation). 
Can anyone give a plausible explanation for that behaviour? TIA

EDIT: (due to comment)
Unfortunately the code is to comprehensive to post it here... both programs are executed on the same machine. Both are fully parallelized (each thread runs an independent copy of the program, just has to tell the other threads when he found the solution). But the instructions counting is done on one thread, cause callgrind is sequencing the program anyway. As mentioned `A` needs far more memory than `B`. 
I'm not expecting an answer that is right on the money, just giving me a few hints what could cause that issue would be nice.

Comment: There are many factors that will influence the duration of a program. Code locality, cache size of the CPU, paralellization posibilities. Without looking at your code and its assembler output it is almost impossible to tell.

Comment: Try also the Google perf tools.

Comment: There are plenty of possibilities. Program `B` could output some log data to the HDD for example. Or have not been optimized properly. Or uses slow algorithms. There is no way to tell without seeing actual code.

Comment: Given that an L1 cache miss is about 10x slower than a cache hit, I suspect that the memory access patterns is much more likely to be the dominant factor than the instruction count.

Comment: A single instruction that causes a stall can be hundreds of times more expensive than a large number of instructions that execute immediately.

Comment: Another way is to roughly compute the algorithmic complexity of both programs.

Comment: @sameerkn the asymptotic complexities are known in tilde-O-Notation, but the interessting question is how the neglected polynomials take effect for different instances.

Comment: Can you provide duration for A and B.

Comment: duration or complexities? duration depends on the size of the instance. Complexities are a bit complicated to provide without further background. If you have further knowledge of LPN and Decoding Algorithms i could provide some information, but otherwise it would be out of scope.

Comment: A full code is not necessary. You should create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You also don't specify the platform you are running it, each CPU has it's own set of do's/don'ts.

For example on x86 there is very little correlation between number of instructions and total execution time, as:

1. x86 at first translates the instructions into internal micro opcodes (uops) and run then those, so it's basically executing completely different code than the machine code visible to the human in the executable. It's also reordering the uops, so even if you simulate the translation, you can't be sure in what order those were executed (unless you simulate whole architecture of the CPU, caches and memory).
2. multiple uops may be executed in single clock tick, or other way, single uop may be blocking the CPU for several clock ticks, so the execution time of any two x86 instructions can differ 100+ time fold (even the same instruction in two runs can have vastly different (~100x) execution time, if it stalls on cache-miss).
3. memory access. Memory is much slower than the CPU, so reading the memory sequentially in predictable pattern and having data as compact as possible (to reuse the caches fully) is more relevant to code speed than number of instructions (algorithm). In some extreme cases a well designed data structure can beat even much better algorithm, like `std::vector<int>` for ~100k items is much faster with random insert/remove, than list, although the vector inser/remove is O(n^2), while list is only about O(n). The only memory at reach of CPU hand is L0 cache, L1 is like on the street, L2 is like travelling to other city, L3 different country. Memory itself is almost like at moon.
4. other I/O access.. if memory is slow, then accessing disc is like going to sun (SSD), or beyond solar system (HDD).

So as you can see, in extreme case the x86 CPU can execute even code which has ~200 instructions + handling 30x more memory as fast as different routine with ~10 instructions. The differences can be really extreme in corner cases, hard to imagine by human by reading the source. That's why on x86 the only valid way to justify your optimizations in code is to profile the code with data close enough to real data. "Optimizing" just by theory, big-o notation, and "gut feel" can backfire easily, that was valid 10-20y back, and even then we profiled the result with tools to verify the gains.

Of course the larger amount of instructions itself can more easily fall off the cache, making the instruction read stall, but if you can create much better data structures, then even 30kiB vs 1kiB of code can be justified (although it risks lot of cache misses while interrupted by OS).

The callgrind web says: *"Optionally, cache simulation and/or branch prediction (similar to Cachegrind) can produce further information about the runtime behavior of an application."*, so you can get even finer data than instruction count, and see if there is some bottleneck, where reorganization of code/data would make it stall less.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm using an AMD64 Plattform. BTW I never said that I'm optimizing my code via the instruction-count or "theory, big-o notation, and "gut feel"". Just wanted to compare them in more then one way. The algorithms are originated in theory, therefore the complexity analysis exists and has nothing to do with my implementation.

Comment: @Memphisd yes, the theoretical complexity is a good general indicator of expected performance, but the implementation can still make huge (order-of in big-O notation) difference. And there's no other reliable way how to measure the implementation impact, than profiling it, in a way as close to real-world usage, as possible. So having 1:10 time difference is pretty much down to the implementation/runtime details only (with minimal input by theory), differences over 1:1000 can be dealt in theory only (almost), ignoring platform/implementation details. In between the HW details starts to matter.

Comment: @Memphisd: hmm.. thinking about it, the important information for you should be about the impact of data structures and memory access pattern. It's sort of completely useless to compare instruction count, before you sorted out data structures (if your data are considerably huge, like in 1e6+ counts). Once you optimize the memory access, then counting instructions starts to matter, but it's one order less important than memory.

Comment: Thanks for all your time writing this... but just to clarify, the 1:10 time difference doesn't need to be suspicious. In fact the only data structure algorithm B uses is a ~500x500 Bit-Matrix, Algorithm A has to store quite more (hashmaps, lists, lots of matrices etc.) and performs better. In theory Algorithm A has also a far better complexity. I was wondering about the fact, that with nearly no memory access and a 1:10 time-difference B has just 3x the instructions of A